# `C-x C-c` closes all windows on OSX

Tags: key-bindings, osx, exit

In OSX, pressing `C-x C-c` closes all Emacs windows instead of only the selected one. This isn't the bahavior I've come to esxpect from using Emacs on Windows, Ubuntu,or CentOS. What's up?

Comment: `C-x C-c` exits Emacs, i.e. it closes all open frames. It works the same on all operating systems. If you just want to close the current frame, use `C-x 5 0`.

Comment: @Lindydancer On other systems opening a new file from outside creates a new instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C-x C-c` is for [Kill Emacs (save-buffers-kill-terminal)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html).

Maybe on other systems you are using `emacsclient`, then

> `C-x C-c` behaves specially if you are using Emacs as a server. If you type it from a client frame, it closes the client connection.

Or maybe you run multiple instances of Emacs?

To close only one frame use `C-x 5 0` or `s-w`.

This command delete current frame or kill Emacs if there are only one frame:

```el
(defun close-frame-or-kill-emacs ()
  "Delete frame or kill Emacs if there are only one frame."
  (interactive)
  (if (> (length (frame-list)) 1)
      (delete-frame)
    (save-buffers-kill-terminal)))
```

Comment: Darn, that's really annoying. `C-x 5 0` and `s-w` won't close the last frame either.

On other systems I just use the default `emacs` or `emacs.exe`, however it comes.

Comment: @Aido, in the absence of the client/server feature, `C-x C-c` has *always* been for quitting the Emacs instance -- which means closing all of its frames.  If you are not using `emacsclient` then the only explanation which makes any sense is that, rather than using multiple frames of a single Emacs instance, you are running multiple instances of Emacs (in which case `C-x C-c` would close only the one you were using at that time).

Comment: @phils Yeah, it looks like that. I've got a script from my dad that randomizes the background color of each instance, and on OSX they're all the same until you close and reopen every window.

Comment: @Aido Added `close-frame-or-kill-emacs` command to answer. Bind it to `s-w` so it will "close" the last frame.

Comment: @muffinmad Good idea, thank you!